# Portable library missing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

In Xamarin Studio (on Mac).  When I try to create a portable library project, I cannot find it in any of the project types.  I believe it used to be available under 'Other -> .Net'

Answer (score 1):

**`New Project` / `Multiplatform` / `Library` / `Portable Library`**

[image]